# Linux not enforcing limits correctly?

Tags: linux, process, limit

As an experiment on a test system, I tried to limit my own number of processes using `/etc/security/limits.conf`. When logged on the system I had 16 processes to my name running (all had ruid, euid and suid to my uid).

I tried first setting the hard and soft limit to 20. I logged out and I could not log back in again because I could not create processes. I raised the limit to 30 and I still could not get in. When I raised the limit to 50 processes I could get in, but `zsh` threw some errors. I found I could create 2 more processes and that was it.

My question is, why if I set the limit to N (in this case, 20) it does not *exactly* enforce N processes as a limit? does it trigger the limit if the user is some% close to it? Otherwise I don't understand why it would not let me create more processes when I still had room under the limit.

Running Linux 4.19 on a standard Debian (systemd based)

EDIT:

To count the processes I did try:

`ps ux`: This yields 14 processes

and for good measure

`cat /proc/*/status | grep Uid | grep 1000 | wc -l`: Which yields 16 processes.

The difference expected due to the extra processes the oneliner uses.

The output of the `grep 1000` (my uid) is:

```
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

Which shows that all are running as real, effective, saved and fsuid 1000 (me)

I believe I have exactly 13 processes because I trust the `ps` and it counts itself, so it should be 13 right?

Comment: You probably have a lot more processes running under your name than you think you do.

Comment: Could you add some info on how you counted the processes? As the above comment states, you may have missed some.

Comment: edited on how I got the number of processes

Comment: I just tried on FreeBSD and was able to restrict the number of processes to *exactly* 10 with: `rctl -a user:imanol:maxproc:deny=10/user`. Not the same OS or limit mechanism, but I used the same methods to validate number of processes, and I would expect Linux to be able to limit to exactly an arbitrary number or devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `man 2 setrlimit`:

> ```
>    RLIMIT_NPROC
>          This is a limit on the number of extant process (or, more precisely on  Linux,  threads)
> ```

Which is, arguably, somewhat counter-intuitive. In any case, it might be that the login process spawns a number of threads that trips the limit when it is set to the order of 20 or 30.

I tested logging in, *then* lowering the limit, and forking simple, single-threaded processess until I got an error. The limits behaved as expected.

Comment: Aaaah that makes sense now. I did check the number of threads with `ps -T ux` and turns out I have 47 active threads on login, which checks out on needing the 50 limit. Somewhat weird and not too in line with the rest of UNIX implementations, but at least it makes sense.

Thanks!